# Inserting datetime values in mysql database through mysqli in php

Tags: php, mysqli

SO I inputted values through a datetime jquery plugin and now i am inserting the values in my database through mysqli php extension .
But the problem is it is not inserting.It always goes into the else condition. I have my form in scheduler.php page from there i am sending values to allforms.php from there i am calling add method of class Scheduler which resides in user.php page

allforms.php page

```
    $operation = $_POST['operation'];
        if($operation == 'add'){
                $request = getSchedule();
                $scheduler = new Scheduler($request['title'],$request['urgency'],$request['meeting'],$request['minfo'],$request['snooze'],$request['textbox'],$request['datetime']);
                $result = $scheduler->add();
                echo $result;
        }   
        function getSchedule(){
            $request = [];
            $request['title'] = isset($_POST['title']);
            $request['urgency'] = isset($_POST['urgency'])?$_POST['urgency']:'';
            $request['meeting'] = isset($_POST['meeting'])?$_POST['meeting']:'';
            $request['minfo'] = isset($_POST['minfo'])?$_POST['minfo']:'';
            $request['snooze'] = isset($_POST['snooze'])?$_POST['snooze']:'';
            $request['textbox'] = isset($_POST['textbox'])?$_POST['textbox']:'';

            $request['datetime'] = isset($_POST['datetime'])?strtotime($_POST['datetime']):'';
            $request['datetime'] = date("Y-m-d",$request['datetime']);
            return $request;
        }
```

scheduler.php Page

```
class Scheduler {
    public $title;
    public $urgency;
    public $meeting;
    public $minfo;
    public $snooze;
    public $textbox;
    public $datetime;
    public function __construct($title,$urgency,$meeting,$minfo,$snooze,$textbox,$datetime){
            $this->title =$title;
            $this->urgency = $urgency;
            $this->meeting = $meeting;
            $this->minfo =$minfo;
            $this->snooze = $snooze;
            $this->textbox = $textbox;
            $this->datetime = $datetime;
            $connection = new Connection();
            $this->connect = $connection->connect();
    }
    public function add(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    Meeting (title, urgency, meeting, minfo, snooze, textbox, datetime) 
                    VALUES ('{$this->title}', '{$this->urgency}', '{$this->meeting}', '{$this->minfo}','{$this->snooze}','{$this->textbox}','{$this->datetime}')";
        $result = $this->connect->query($sql);
        if($result)
            {
                return  $this->title ." has been registered ";
            }else {
                return  "Some error occured and we couldn't add the event";
            }
        }

    }
```

scheduler.php Page

```
 <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="allforms.php" >
            <div>
                <label><b>Title</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your title here" name="title" >
            </div>
              <div>
                <label><b>Urgency Level</b></label>
                <select name="urgency" class="textbox" >
                  <option value="Low">Low</option>
                  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                  <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><b>Meeting Type</b></label>
                <select name="meeting" class="textbox">
                  <option value="Telephonic">Telephonic</option>
                  <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
                  <option value="Online">Online</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><b>Meeting Info</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="minfo" placeholder="Enter location name , number or skype id ,etc.">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><b>Snooze</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Snooze time in minutes" name="snooze" class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><b>Description</b></label>
                <textarea name="textbox" class="textbox"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Date/Time of the meeting</b></label>
                    <input type='text' id="datetimepickr" class="form-control" name="datetime">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="add">
            <button type="submit" name="add">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you dump echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit();  your post variable in  function getSchedule(){, and show your date format? have set the default date? is datetimepicker working ?

Comment: if i print value of date time in getschedule() and put a die afterwards its printing 2017/08/05 without time and if i replace strtotime and the next line with a normal $_POST['datetime'] it is printing 2017/08/05 13:00 but still its not inserting to the db @MuhammadAkberKhan

Comment: Is your query successful (`if($result)`)? Also what is the type of your DB `datetime` field?

Comment: Its not successful it is going into the else condition , i have set the field  type to datetime(6) only. @xander

Comment: if your DB datetime field is of type datetime then, in your function getSchedule(){, change date format, like this  $request['datetime'] = date("Y-m-d H:i",$request['datetime']);

Comment: Ok if you get an SQL error try running this in the else block `trigger_error($this->connect->error, E_USER_ERROR);` to display the error.

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan its working now after defining datetime format in getschedule, Thank you very much

Comment: @xander Thank you its working now

Comment: @mayank singh, can you upvote correct comments?

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan Its a new account so i dont have privilage to upvote comments if you can put an answer then i can upvote that.

Comment: ok thanks, i have put my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your datetime format,

```
  function getSchedule(){
            $request = [];
            $request['title'] = isset($_POST['title']);
            $request['urgency'] = isset($_POST['urgency'])?$_POST['urgency']:'';
            $request['meeting'] = isset($_POST['meeting'])?$_POST['meeting']:'';
            $request['minfo'] = isset($_POST['minfo'])?$_POST['minfo']:'';
            $request['snooze'] = isset($_POST['snooze'])?$_POST['snooze']:'';
            $request['textbox'] = isset($_POST['textbox'])?$_POST['textbox']:'';

            $request['datetime'] = isset($_POST['datetime'])?strtotime($_POST['datetime']):'';
            $request['datetime'] = date("Y-m-d H:i",$request['datetime']);
            return $request;
        }
```